# Is This "Type Punning" Well-Defined?

Tags: c

I was wondering, is casting to and from a pointer to an incomplete type undefined behavior?

```
struct _obj;
typedef _obj obj;

typedef struct{
    int val;
} obj_int;

void print_stuff(obj* o){
    printf("%d\n", ((*obj_int)(o)) -> val);
}
```

Comment: Where'd `obj* o` come from?  Another cast, or was `struct _obj` completed and an actual instance of `struct _obj` exists and `o` is its address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually.

Standard 6.3.2.3/7:

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different
>   object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the
>   pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the
>   result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is
>   converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of
>   the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers
>   to the remaining bytes of the object.

So if `o` points at any struct object whose first member is an `int`, you're fine.  If it points at the beginning of memory obtained from `malloc`, where the representation of an `int` has been written, you're fine.  But if it points at a `char[sizeof(int)]` or some such thing, you might have alignment issues.

Comment: I agree with "if `o` points at any struct object whose first member is an `int`, you're fine".  It isn't clear what "the representation of an `int` has been written", it doesn't sound like the right condition (which is that an lvalue of type `int` or `char` was used to store the value).

Comment: Which version of the standard is this? The words "incomplete type" don't appear in 6.3.2.3/7 in my copy.

Comment: @Paul: 6.3.2.3, not 6.2.3.2

Comment: In C11, incomplete object types still fall into the category of *object type*, see 6.2.5/1.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, it was a typo, I corrected it to 6.3.2.3. Agree on 6.2.5/1, just curious whether my standard is out of date or not.

Comment: @Paul: No, yours is more up-to-date.  aschepler quoted from C99, and in the newer C11 the "or incomplete type" is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You have given insufficient information to answer your question. *If* you cast an `obj_int*` to `obj*` and then pass that to `print_stuff`, *then* your code is legit according to the C standard because you're allowed to cast a pointer to another pointer type and back. However, if the argument to `print_stuff` was obtained in any other way, then you have undefined behavior.